# which method of mapper class shall be used to read the file in distributed cache

Tags: java, hadoop

You want to populate an associative array in order to perform a map-side join. You’ve decided to
put this information in a text file, place that file into the DistributedCache and read it in your
Mapper before any records are processed.
Indentify which method in the Mapper you should use to implement code for reading the file and
populating the associative array?

map or configure ??

Comment: Use mapper to read the file in the distributed cache and can use cacheReader.readLine() to read the file lines.

Comment: Correcting my question - which method of the mapper class - map() or configure() ?

Comment: try using map() to read the file from distributed cache and then use cacheReader.readLine() to read the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the setup() method.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html#setup%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context%29

It gets called once at the initialization of each mapper task. So if there's anything you want to do before the map task starts to read the key/value pairs through the map method (such as, in your question, to read a file off the distributed cache and populate some member vars with the info), then that is the place to do it.

Comment: Can you please comment for the latest answer. The configure method answer is confusion me further. Do the configure method gets called for every map task ?

Answer (score 1):

```
class IndexMapperExample implements Mapper {
  void configure(JobConf conf) {
  try {
     String stopwordCacheName = new Path(HDFS_STOPWORD_LIST).getName();
  Path [] cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
  if (null != cacheFiles && cacheFiles.length > 0) {
    for (Path cachePath : cacheFiles) {
      if (cachePath.getName().equals(stopwordCacheName)) {
        loadStopWords(cachePath);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  System.err.println("IOException reading from distributed cache");
  System.err.println(ioe.toString());
  }
}
```

In above code snippet,file of distributed cache gets read in configure method.
that means distributed cache gets read in configure method.